# VPN connection reset

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have a device running ArchLinux and OpenVPN, which was connecting to VPN server without problems until recently. Now it can't connect, with the following output that keeps looping indefinitely: http://pastebin.com/BU6aiBVn

Is the WARNING message from the log the reason for this? I have checked the link provided in the log: http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm but I am currently using easy-rsa 2.0 to create the certificate and I am using it when connecting.

How can I investigate further? I guess this is not enough data for anyone to really know what is happening, but I am not sure what else to provide, so please say in the comments what else is needed for debugging this issue, and I will edit my question.

**UPDATE**
Also, now it seems that sometimes I get this error, but I am not sure what is different in such case:

```
Mar 31 09:39:32 alarmpi openvpn[530]: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mar 31 09:39:32 alarmpi openvpn[530]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mar 31 09:39:32 alarmpi openvpn[530]: Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Mar 31 09:39:32 alarmpi openvpn[530]: SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
```

**UPDATE 2**
As per MadHatter suggestion, I tried connecting via Telnet from the client, and it seems to work:

```
[root@alarmpi ~]# telnet <SERVER_IP> 443
Trying <SERVER_IP>...
Connected to <SERVER_IP>.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**UPDATE 3**
It would seem that after the openvpn restart, clients are now able to connect. I am not sure what caused this or how it got overcome, but I can't seem to reproduce this issue at the moment. I will try some more and if I can't reproduce I will delete the question.

Comment: At the moment, the issue seems to be much lower-level than certificate issues; basic connectivity seems to be failing.  Handily, you seem to be using TCP on server port 443; could you try from the client `telnet server.ip.address 443`, and paste the results into your question?

Comment: @MadHatter: It seems to work, as described in my update.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue, I just resolved it by doing this,

1. open the firewall and allow 443
2. make sure you are not establishing same connection anywhere else with your cert file or Password( only one VPN connection is allowed, If you want multiple client to be connected don't forget to use "--duplicate-cn " option)